# Fundamental Counting Principle Problem (How many possible passwords can I create)

Tags: combinatorics

I am to create a six character password that consists of 2 lowercase letters and 4 numbers. The letters and numbers can be mixed up in any order and I can also repeat the same number and letter as well. How many possible passwords are there?

What I have pieced together so far:

Well, from the fundamental counting principle, we would definitely need $26^2\times10^4$ but obviously this is not all the possibilities since I can rearrange letters and numbers. Since it is a password the order matters so would I try and do a permuation of some sort like $^6P_2$ since there are $6$ slots to try to rearrange $2$ objects (letters)?

Thanks!

Comment: You have the answer. Just multiply $\binom{6}{2}$ by $26^210^4$.

Comment: @robjohn Right then. I was about to write an answer, but you pre-empted it $\ddot\smile$

Comment: @ParclyTaxel: go ahead and write it. There should really be an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're just a little wrong on the letters-numbers arrangement part; it's $\binom62=15$, not $^6P_2=30$ (since we do the arrangement before the character assignment).

Now multiply this with your (correct) value of $26^2×10^4$ character assignments to get the final answer: $26^2×10^4×\binom62$.